# Is the position of white space in HTML syntax or preference?

Tags: html

I am really sorry for the vague title but I cannot figure a better way to word it, its better with an example.

Is this code below correct?

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
```

Or this?

```
<body>
    <h1>
        Hello
    </h1>
    <h1>
        Hello    
    </h1>
    <h1>
        Hello
    </h1>
</body>
```

What is this called and is it a written rule how line breaks and white space should be used in HTML?

Comment: Both is correct. Since your heading will be a short and well readable line, there is nothing wrong putting it all together in one line.

Comment: Additional whitespace can cause larger file sizes, in turn, longer loading. While this might be minute, if you can easily improve, do it. Minification tools can can help with this, essentially reducing all the white space and restructuring your code to one line before you deploy or use in a production environment. Ultimately, how you format your HTML wouldn't matter with minification.